# error (261, -1003) android error in audio play

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to play an audio on click of an Image. When I run the app and click on the Image I get below error in the console:

Logcat

```
06-17 17:04:29.412: I/SurfaceTextureClient(7979): [0x52d0e358] frames:14, duration:243.320999, fps:0.057537
06-17 17:04:29.536: V/Provider/Setting(7979): from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
06-17 17:04:30.719: V/Provider/Setting(7979): from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
06-17 17:04:30.993: D/dalvikvm(7979): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1597K, 29% free 31208K/43703K, paused 12ms+8ms, total 103ms
06-17 17:04:30.994: D/dalvikvm(7979): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 29ms
06-17 17:04:31.009: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(7979): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
06-17 17:04:31.015: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(7979): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
06-17 17:04:38.476: V/Provider/Setting(7979): from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
06-17 17:04:38.479: D/MediaPlayer(7979): mPlayerID = 169
06-17 17:04:38.494: I/dalvikvm(7979): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
06-17 17:04:38.524: E/MediaPlayer(7979): error (261, -1003)
06-17 17:04:38.531: I/SurfaceTextureClient(7979): [void android::SurfaceTextureClient::init()] debug.stc.fps: 3000 ms
06-17 17:04:38.539: E/MediaPlayer(7979): Error (261,-1003)

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();     

try {
    mp.setDataSource("server_path/abc.mp3");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
dialog.setMessage(v.getResources().getText(R.string.loading).toString());   
dialog.show();      

mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
mp.prepareAsync();
```

I tried the solution given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902953/closing-mediaplayer-properly) but it did not work.

Comment: change from prepareAsync() to only mp.prepare();

Comment: tried this now no error (261, -1003) error , but the audio doesnt play.

Comment: I would just try the following steps: 1. mp = new MediaPlayer(); 2. mp.reset(); 3. mp.setDataSource("be_sure_the_path_is_correct.mp3"); 4.)mp.prepeare(); 5.)mp.start().

Answer (score 2):

Even though its late to reply this, I thought somebody who face this problem will get immediate answer.  Error (261, -1003) is no where documented.  This error will be thrown if there is no internet connection and  you are specifying a remote video file URL as video source and  you didn't provided a error listener to MediaPlayer/VideoVew class.

Comment: i faced the same issue while live view playing. i thought error occurred when video can't read from URL due to auth problem of URL / media.

Answer (score 0):

26 means `PVMFInfoErrorHandlingStart`, just an error indication
The error is -11, which means `PVMFErrTimeout`.